# Compare two dependent fields in java Comparator

Tags: java

Using java Comparator I want to get the lowest index which is having a higher value.

- **Case 1**

```
| Index | Score |
| ----- | ------|
| 1     | 100   |
| 1     | 110   |
| 2     | 150   |
```

*Output should be 1 - 110*

- **Case 2**

```
| Index | Score |
| ----- | ----- |
| 1     | null  |
| 1     | null  |
| 2     | 150   |
| 2     | 110   |
```

*Output should be 2 - 150*

The below code is giving exception and also I know it will not provide expected output.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CompareMe {
private int index;
private Integer score;

public CompareMe(int index, Integer score) {
    this.index = index;
    this.score = score;
}

public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}

public Integer getScore() {
    return score;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<CompareMe> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new CompareMe(1, 100));
    list.add(new CompareMe(1, 110));
    list.add(new CompareMe(2, 150));

    CompareMe max = Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparingInt(CompareMe::getIndex).reversed()
            .thenComparing(CompareMe::getScore));

    System.out.println(max.getIndex() + "-" + max.getScore());

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new CompareMe(1, null));
    list.add(new CompareMe(1, null));
    list.add(new CompareMe(2, 150));
    list.add(new CompareMe(2, 110));

    max = Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparingInt(CompareMe::getIndex).reversed()
            .thenComparing(CompareMe::getScore));
    System.out.println(max.getIndex() + "-" + max.getScore());
}
}
```

Comment: @Chaosfire I have added the code which I am trying to get the expected output

Comment: @Neo Ok, looks like NPE is striking your comparators. How should we deal with null scores? Filter them out completely or give them lower priority?

Comment: Filter them out completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to remove null scores completely, it's better to keep the current comparator and use `Stream` instead.

```
Comparator<CompareMe> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(CompareMe::getIndex).reversed().thenComparing(CompareMe::getScore);
CompareMe max = list.stream()
            .filter(cm -> cm.getScore() != null)
            .max(comparator)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("empty list?"));
```

Changing the comparators to take into account null scores would complicate the index comparison unnecessarily(null score basically reverses current index comparison and both fields need to be taken into account) and very similar null checks need to be added when comparing scores.

Comment: *null score basically reverses current index comparison and both fields need to be taken into account* - good point, this approach is more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `score` can be `null` you might make the second part of your *comparator* to be *null-safe*. For that, you can use [`Comparator.nullsFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst(java.util.Comparator)), which creates a *null-friendly comparator* that considers `null` to be *less* than *non-null*.

Also, in order to get the correct result in the first part of the *comparator* (*which is responsible for comparing indices*) we need to take into account whether the score is `null` or not.

```
max = Collections.max(list, 
    Comparator.comparingInt((CompareMe item) -> 
            (item.getScore() == null ? -1 : item.getIndex()) * (-1)).reversed()
        .thenComparing(CompareMe::getScore, 
            Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

This *comparator* with give the correct output if objects having *non-null* score are present in the input. But we can't ensure only by changing the *compactor* that the result will have a *non-null* score.

The better approach would be to eliminate `null` values instead of treating them as a special case. It can be done by using `Collection.removeIf()` and then you can safely apply the same comparator that you've listed in the question:

```
List<CompareMe> list = 
    List.of(new CompareMe(1, null), new CompareMe(1, null),
            new CompareMe(2, 150), new CompareMe(2, 110));
    
list.removeIf(item -> item.getScore() == null);

max = Collections.max(list,
            Comparator.comparingInt(CompareMe::getIndex).reversed()
                .thenComparing(CompareMe::getScore));
        
System.out.println(max.getIndex() + "-" + max.getScore());
```

*Output:*

```
2-150
```